# Detect if video/audio is being played at server side

Tags: hyperlink, video-streaming

I want to detect if a shared link contaning video/audio is being played, and after a duration show some advert, end of video/audio show an offer. The link can be shared on any media email, chat, website. I dont really have any control over the front end to send some events back.

I can not manipulate the content of the media, they are provided from a different source. I wrap the source in a new link like ”bitly” that will redirect anyone opening the link to me. So I know that they have clicked, and how many times, but have they started watching, stopped, how long did they watch etc is what I want to get at.

I was thinking that I probably need to have my own player, but that seems a lot of extra work which I want to avoid.

I would appreciate help of anyone who has done tracking of this kind to give me some hints on how to approach this problem, maybe there is a better way that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you are asking for is server-side ad insertion or SSAI. This is totally possible with a number of streaming formats. Eyevinn has a [good overview](https://medium.com/@eyevinntechnology/understanding-server-side-dynamic-ad-insertion-d7ed90e34aa2) about how it works and things that support it.

It's not really possible with simple MP4 files, but if you use something like [HLS](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) or [DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP), there are loads of options.

Comment: Thanks interesting read, however I'm not sure SSAI allows for event tracking of clients player activities. This is more embedding while you are streaming right, still one way communication?

Comment: @user1043825 you can track on your HTTP server whether or not a specific client has asked for a specific segment. I don't know of any readymade tools to do that. But there would be nothing stopping you from parsing those logs to see if the ads were delivered to the clients. However, a lot of advertisers want's information on "viewability" I.e. was the video player visible on the client devices when playing ads, and that is only accessible client side.